# "Jekyll Serve" causing errors

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, command-prompt

### ERROR in command prompt

C:\portfolio>jekyll serve
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:
356:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'mi
nima x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available
on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/resolver.rb:331:in`each'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/resolver.rb:331:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/resolver.rb:200:in`start'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/resolver.rb:184:in `resolve'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/definition.rb:200:in`resolve'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/definition.rb:185:in`specs_for'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/environment.rb:19:in`requested_specs'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
.rb:95:in`setup'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/pl
ugin_manager.rb:36:in `require_from_bundler'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/exe/jekyll:9:
in`'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/bin/jekyll:23:in`'

---

image reference if its easier to read that way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNiwd.png

I'm getting this error when trying to use "jekyll serve"

I installed ruby and the ruby gems as well

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem

Ruby has issues on 2.2 + for windows 8.1 on using jekyll serve

see 
 https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3814